# Translating voltage using op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, sensor

I want to translate -200uV to 800uV coming from a sensor to a range of 0-5V using Op-amp. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way you can do it. Now, can you be more specific? What have you tried and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to start. I can use only Op-Amp and other passive components. The problem is I don't see a linear shift, so how can any amplifier produce this kind of non-linear shift?

Comment: 1. Are you restricted to just use one op-amp, or can you use two or more? 2. What do you mean non-linear shift? Edit your question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Did you ever googled something? There's plenty of op-amp resources & tutorials out there...

Answer (score 2):

Amongst the problems you have are getting high gain in a single stage, DC offsets of the amplifier (which for cheap ones exceed the input voltage range), and making sure the amplifier can cope with the negative input.

You say nothing about the output impedance of the sensor, or the speed you want, or whether you want to stick to single rail opamps or can cope with dual rail, so some assumptions must be made.

The two simplest toplogies are inverting, and non-inverting, below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ63Wj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inverting topology uses R3 and R4 to provide a gain of 5000, to boost your 1mV range up to 5v. Most amplifiers will have enough gain to do this.

It assumes the amplifier has an input common mode range that includes ground, and an output that will swing 0 to 5v. This can either be a rail-to-rail amplifier with a 0/5v supply, or any amplifier with appropriate power rails.

Most cheap amplifiers will have an offset voltage in the several mV, so it's a nonsense to attempt to set the input voltage tighter than this. What we now need to do is adjust the input offset until the output voltage falls in our 5v range. I've shown a current source of 1uA. If this is connected to R1, it will lift the voltage of the +ve input by 1mV, increasing the output by 5v. If it is connected to the R3/R4 junction (the summing junction) then it will reduce the output by 5v. Ajusting the value of this current source, which need only be a high value resistor from the 5v supply, and choosing which point it's connected to, will allow you to offset the amplifier's offset error, and accomodate the DC input shift from your sensor.

The non-inverting topology to the right has much the same considerations. It offers a high input impedance to the sensor. As before, the 1mV range of the sensor is swamped by the input offset of the amplifier. You can connect an offsetting current into the R5/R6 junction, but you need to be able to swing this current both positive and negative if you want control of offset voltage in both directions.

You can obtain some single op-amps with input voltage offset adjust pins. I don't know whether any of these versions are available in 5v rail-to-rail. Certainly TL071 has offset adjust, but you would need rails of at least +10v and -5v to make it cover the range.

You would need to choose an amplifier with a low tempco of input offset voltage, if your carefully set up input offset was not to drift around with temperature. For instance, the LM324 (popular cheap low voltage amplifier, but not rail to rail!) has a 7uV/C input tempco. A change in temperature of 5 degrees C could look like an input signal of 3.5% of full scale! There are much better ones, OP177 for instance (0.3uV/C).

You can get chopper stabilised opamps, which have very stable DC offsets, and are not ruinously expensive.

You might want to look at in-amps, instrumentation amplifiers, and see how they improve of some of the limitations of single amplifiers.

Answer (score 1):

-200uV to 800uV is a span of 1mV. The shifting is a lot easier with two op-amps. How about a gain of -500 inverting amp to give 0.1V to -0.4V. Use a second inverting amp with a pot to produce an offset of 1V at the output, and a gain of 10.

Any op-amp application book will have these common circuits. It is easier to precisely handle the offset with a lower gain in the second amp. If you don't have a bandwidth problem, go ahead and use big resistors, like 4K and 2M for the 500 gain.

If your sensor has high output impedance, you will need another OA or two to make an instrumentation amp or a low gain or gain of 1 follower.

Answer (score 0):

Spec :

- Input : -200uV to 800uV
- Output:  0-5V
- Source impedance:  unknown
- Bandwidth or slew rate: unknown

I would consider an instrument Amp for best CMRR and CM range near/below ground or use a negative supply.  OA needs 5V Rail-Rail CMOS output. Use pot for offset voltage, if needed, possibly not.
[image]
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/AD8293G80ARJZ-R7/AD8293G80ARJZ-R7TR-ND/1938193

Comment: That IA has a fixed gain of 80 (version A) or 160 (version B) - how does this produce an output signal of 5 volts for an input of 1 mV?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean 'linear' you mean proportional. What that means is that you are going to have to provide a reference voltage to create an offset.

The gain required is obviously 5000. You need to offset the voltage at the input by +200uV or the output by +200uV * 5000 = +1V.

One way to do this would be to take a simple non-inverting amplifier with a gain of +5000 and modify it to get the required offset.

Since this is obviously a homework problem, you should do your best to solve this yourself.

I will tell you that you can do this with a single ideal op-amp and three resistors. **Approximate** resistor ratio is (-Vref/1V)*5000:5000:1 for |Vref| >> 1V.

Answer (score 0):

This discrete "opamp" needs only 3 microAmps, easily works with inputs of -200uV to +800uV, and provides Gain of 41X. How precise must the gain be?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fem6BA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>